# minimum control frequency for closed loop

Tags: control-theory

I'd like to determine the lowest practical control frequency of a LQR controller needed for a double integrator-like system. What I do is to build the LTI representation

$$sys \triangleq A, B, C, D$$ of the system, and convert it into its discrete counterparts Ad Bd by doing 
$$[A_d,B_d] = c2d(A,B,Ts)$$
where $Ts$ is the sampling frequency of the controller, that is assigned and equal to 20 Hz. Then, I compute the lqr gains by using the function dlqr. 
$$K = dlqr(A,B,Q,R,Ts)$$
I tuned the controller by penalizing state errors (through $Q$) and control efforts (through $R$) and looking at the simulation results. The controller has to counteract errors on position and velocity, as well as parameters uncertainties.

What is the analytical tool I can use to determine the lowest control frequency? As far as I know, with the $R$ matrix I penalize the control magnitude, but I read somewhere that it also controls the closed-loop bandwidth of the system. How do I determine the minimum frequency that stabilizes the system?

Comment: what do you mean by minimum frequency? Sampling frequency?

Comment: Hi, no I mean the lowest closed-loop bandwidth I can allocate for ensuring the controller to work well in presence of disturbances.

Comment: You can check the bandwidth afterwards if you are going to use state feedback with LQR. Otherwise you have to include performance weights and perform an hinfsyn design to include bandwidth constraints.

Comment: thanks. I know that you can see the closed-loop bandwidth by looking at the frequency in the bode plot where the response goes down to -3dB. but how I can I see it for MIMO systems? if I look at each I/O pair I can get a closed-loop bandwidth for each, but what is the one for the system? the smallest of all of them?